# Uploading video to YouTube using Java Script or Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, youtube-api, google-developers-console, video-upload

I have a video which I want to upload it to  *YouTube* using Java Script or Apps Script. I know that I will need a **blob URL** to do that   I have that too. I just want to know how to upload Videos using ***Java Script or Apps Script***. Thanks In Advance:)

Comment: Check out the official sample code from Google: [upload_video.js](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/upload_video.js). Also go read the [README file](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/README.md) too (it contains helping info about the uploading procedure implemented).

Comment: Thanks A Lot, Can You please attach the code here because I am New in Java Script?

Comment: And can you also attach a working example.

Comment: The sample code I quoted above *constitutes a working example.*

Comment: The example is not working can you please add a code. I have tried it here but still not working [Failed code](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GPNRVEQYE9Z4)